# How do I update data with Entity Framework Core when I migrate?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

So, I have my system, and I use Entity Framework Core (code first) to create the tables and save all my data, and everything works fine.

However, time pass, and I need to change some of the entity classes, maybe a property change type, maybe I decide I need to change the values (for example, I decide I used the wrong enum and I need to use a different one), and so on.

How do I do that?

I mean, sure, I have the migrationBuilder.AlterColumn method, but although it has the ability to change the type of the column, there is no way (That I can see) to control the migration of the values. All I see is how I can insert a single value for all the objects, which is ofcourse wrong.

What I was expecting is for a place for me to insert a function that would receive the old value and return the new one. However, I don't see any way to do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: `migrationBuilder.Sql(…)`

Comment: @IvanStoev This hardly seems like a solution. I mean, sure, technically one could do pretty much everything with SQL commands, but this beats the entire point of using Entity Framework Core and the Migration system.

Comment: I know. And I don't like it either. But that's all we have from EF Core currently for such scenarios.

Comment: @IvanStoev How do you think I should do it in SQL, in that case?